# Location of iostream.h in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc

I am getting back into C++ world after nearly a decade. I have installed GCC and wrote a preliminary program on my Windows 7 box. I have the following question:

When I say `#include <iostream.h>` , I get an error saying file not found. I have to say `#include <iostream>` to get it working. Further, when I go to the folder where GCC is installed, I could not find the hearder file by either name. Where is iostream getting picked from?

Comment: did you try `locate iostream.h` ? And on what os are you working on ?

Comment: You really have been away a long time! The headers ending with `.h` was done away with in C++03. All standard library headers now have no extension. I recommend you look at e.g. [this reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) to see a up to date reference of the modern standard library.

Comment: There is no `iostream.h` in C++ std library, only `iostream` (without extension).

Comment: Usually its something like /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream

Comment: It would be interesting to know [why](http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/iostream.html).

Comment: Perhaps you missed the link in my comment ;-). It would be interesting to know why the transition happened, so you might want to check out the link.

Comment: Interesting that of 6 comments, only one answered the question.

Answer (score 7):

`<iostream>` is the standard C++ header you need to include. Where it is depends on your platform. On mine, it is in

> /usr/include/c++/4.4.3/iostream

You can find out details of `g++` configuration with

> g++ --verbose

This prints out, among other things,

> --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4

Comment: Thanks for answering that question directly.

Answer (score 5):

The `.h` headers (such as `iostream.h`) have been deprecated in favor of the "modern" style headers (`iostream`). This ensures that the implementation does not need to provide the headers as a file physically located on the disk. It is free to choose any appropriate implementation.

For example, `<math.h>` requires the implementation to provide a file with this name, but if you only specify `<cmath>`, the implementation is free to provide the math utilities as it pleases, without the need for physical file.

Additionally, the `.h` headers put their declarations in the global namespace, whereas the "non-.h" headers put their declarations in the `std` namespace. As a result, the new headers are unlikely to cause any naming conflicts.

**Edit** As [Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch) pointed out in the comment, this notion is not restricted to C++ alone, but the C standard also supports it.

Comment: The answer you provided is unhelpful and borderline rude.  I appreciate that accidents happen, I make them too, but once an answer has been submitted you shouldn't expect that we will know that you are editing it to make it more useful.  If you edit this answer so that it is helpful and not rude, and I see the edit, I'll gladly remove the downvote.

Comment: @JohnDibling I didn't mean to be rude. It was a poor attempt at being funny. My apologies for that. Sorry for my previous comment. You are of course, right in downvoting poor answers, regardless of accidents.

Comment: @aleguna I know, and I use them too. Like I said above, it was a poor attempt at being funny. My apologies.

Comment: Downvote removed, yhanks for editing. I like humor too, just bear in mind that on a website you lose all the non-verbal communication. What may seem funny in your head might not translate well to the written word.

Comment: The fact that an `#include`-d header does not need to be a file is not specific to C++; the C standard also supports that notion. In practice, with GCC on Linux, all headers *are* files.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, that's a good point, and I agree. However, the question seemed specific to C++, and I wrote the answer based on what I had read in "The C++ Programming Language". Allow me to edit the answer mentioning this.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `iostream.h` header in C++, these were around in pre-standard days. No C++ standard library header ends in `.h`.

If your compiler installation is sane you should never have to add the directory containing the standard library headers to your include directories -- the compiler already knows best where to look.

Answer (score 2):

On my Windows box, `iostream` (now without `.h`) is at `:\cygwin\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.5.3\include`. (I was searching it because of an eclipse error and searched Google and my HD.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can find it in source code of GCC:
`libstdc++-v3/include/std/iostream`
**Without** `.h` extension
Example for `GCC-4.7`

Comment: Of course It's not the C version, it's for C++ and has dependences

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-H` [preprocessor option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) of GCC to have it display each included header.

And as others told you, standard C++ headers don't end anymore with `.h`or `.hh`

(My suggestion is to use `.hh` for your own C++ header files, and `.cc` for your C++ source files; I also suggest to use GCC 4.7 and to code against the [C++2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) standard, notably with the `auto` keyword for "type inference" of initialized local variables)

Comment: My suggestion is to use `.hpp` for headers and `.cpp` for sources, like Boost ;)